# Determine mobile hardware manufacturer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mobile

I'm writing some .NET CF code that will sometimes run on Motorola devices and other times on Intermec devices. Depending on which device I'm running on, I want to use that manufacturers libraries for what I am doing. Is there an easy way in .NET CF to determine the hardware manufacturer (and ideally model)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SystemParametersInfoString method from coredll.dll.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);

if (SystemParametersInfoString(SPI_GETPLATFORMTYPE, sb.Capacity, sb, 0) != 0)
{
    String name = sb.ToString();        
}
```

Change SPI_GETPLATFORMTYPE to SPI_GETOEMINFO or play with it. you might fine more..

Comment: Thanks that worked for me! For anyone else who happens across it, this is some sample C# code:

private const int SPI_GETOEMINFO = 258;
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo", SetLastError = true)]

private static extern int SystemParametersInfoString(int uiAction, int uiParam, StringBuilder pvParam, int fWinIni);

public static string GetPlatformName()
{
 try
 {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
  if (SystemParametersInfoString(SPI_GETOEMINFO, sb.Capacity, sb, 0) != 0)
  {
   return sb.ToString();
  }
 }
 catch{}
 return "<Unknown platform>";
}